# Enable CDC on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cdc

I am trying to enable CDC on SQL Server by running the command `EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db` but I keep getting the message:

Could not update the metadata that indicates database X is enabled for Change Data Capture.
The failure occurred when executing the command 'create user cdc'.

The error returned was 15562: 'The module being executed is not trusted. Either the owner of the database of the module needs to be granted authenticate permission, or the module needs to be digitally signed.'. Use the action and error to determine the cause of the failure and resubmit the request.

I've tried adding and removing `sa` as db_onwer; I've tried to create cdc user manually, but nothing works.

What else could I try?

Comment: Maybe a database owner issue. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441785/could-not-update-the-metadata-that-indicates-database-x-is-enabled-for-change-da

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  I found it was related to a database trigger we had on the DB.  Disabled the trigger and it worked.  Was tipped off by comments here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/31e1c9c4-a15d-4f38-ab59-2bb0851e7d63/unable-to-enable-a-database-for-cdc?forum=sqlreplication

Comment: Hi do you know what the contents of your link was, its dead for me? Im having an issue and i dont know if your answer would help

Comment: Shoot... yeah that link is dead for me too.  I don't remember the contents of the link, but basically it made me realize that the trigger on the DB is what prevented CDC from working properly.